# emacs: Is it possible to match strings with balanced parens with emacs regex?

Tags: regex, emacs

Something like this:
  http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide083.html

In other words I want to match successfully on `{ { foo } { bar} }` but not on `{ { foo }` .

I see it's possible in perl, [and in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx).  Is it possible in emacs regex?

Comment: ha!  SO is funny.  As I search for more hints on this, typing in "emacs regex balanced" into google, I get *this question* as the first hit.  heh heh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, so far Perl/PCRE and .NET are the only regex flavors that support arbitrary nesting (recursive patterns).

Comment: Mmkay, you get an upvote even though this is not the answer I wanted.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. But I'm not at all sure if recursive regexes are a Good Thing. They can get complicated enough without that already. A parser combined with a regex looks more sensible to me.

Comment: Meh! "regular expressions" that have been extended to the point that they can do this are not actually "regular" anymore. Not that this is a bad thing, necessarily, but the evolution of the tool has made the terminology obsolete.

Comment: @dmckee, What makes a regular expression, *regular*?  By "not regular" do you just mean that the extensions are not universally supported?  I'll buy that.  But I did not know that recursion, or the ability to do balanced matching, was an extension, or was not supported. Which is why I asked.   @Tim, I think you're right, and that's what I will likely do.

Comment: @Cheeso: The term "regular expression" has been stretched over the years. A true regular expression would not allow for backreferences or lookaround since those are not "regular" anymore. Recursiveness is just another extra feature that extends what regular expressions can do - a theoretical computer scientist would probably shudder at the terminology...

Comment: @Cheeso: as Tim said, the "Regular" actually refers to a very specific thing. And the inability to match nesting depths is actually part of the definition of regular. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Deciding_whether_a_language_is_regular ). To be fair though, regular expressions engines have been misnamed for at least a decade or two.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I see. Thanks for the link.  I don't understand any of that stuff, the Myhill-Nerode theorem or the pumping lemma or free monoids, and I don't care to delve into it. But at least now I am clear that there is a formal definition for "regular".

Answer (score 2):

No, but if you have a particular use case to discuss you'll often find that you don't need regexes. Simple state-machines to match parenthases are pretty simple to write in lisp. Looking at the source of Paredit is a good place to start.

Comment: yes, well in my case the paren parsing is already done.  It's within cc-mode, so I can just use `(forward-sexp)` with regex matching on either side.  I was just hoping to be able to do it with a single regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still interested have a look at [cexp.el](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/cexp).

It is just a hack but maybe serves your purpose.

You can search for combined regular and balanced expressions with `cexp-search-forward`.
The built-in `re-search-forward` is used for regular expressions and so its syntax rules apply. Balanced expressions can be matched with the additional syntax elements `\!(` and `\!)`.

The most serious restriction is that balanced expressions may not occur in groups. So a construct like `\!(^{ \(\!(^{.*}$\!)\)+ }$\!)` does not work because of the group containing the inner balanced expression.

Nevertheless, one useful example is matching TeX-definitions like

```tex
\def\mdo#1{{\def\next{\relax}\def\tmp{#1}\ifx\next\tmp\else\def\next{#1\mdo}\expandafter}\next}
```

with combined expressions like

```
\\def\\[[:alpha:]]+\(#[0-9]\)*\!(^{.*}$\!)
```

The search via cexp-search-forward with the above cexp returns the limits for the following groups:

1. The beginning and the end of the full match
2. The limits of the match for the regular expression before the balanced expression, i.e. `\def\mdo#1`
3. The limits of the captured group in the first regular expression, i.e., `#1`
4. The limits of the balanced expression, i.e., `{{\def\next{\relax}\def\tmp{#1}\ifx\next\tmp\else\def\next{#1\mdo}\expandafter}\next}`

Comment: Consider expanding your answer with some excerpt from the referenced page. See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for details why bare links are not considered good answers.